# How to apply a class to a validation error message?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Simple Form, as it's shown in the **UserType.php** code source.

Besides, i'm using **fosuserbundle**, in my case, when i try to create a user that already exist with same username or a user with different password/Repeatedpassword , a new validation message is shown up .

**The question is :** How to apply custom CSS/Html Class to that validation message ?.

> UserType.php :

```
->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(

    'invalid_message' => 'The passwords must be identical.',

    'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
    'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeate Password'),
)
```

> User.php :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="usernameCanonical", errorPath="username", message="fos_user.username.already_used", groups={"Default", "Registration", "Profile"})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="emailCanonical", errorPath="email", message="fos_user.email.already_used", groups={"Default", "Registration", "Profile"})
 */
class User extends BaseUser {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * 
     */
    protected $id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default form templates by adding your own to your bundle. Examples of this can be found [here](https://github.com/symfony/twig-bridge/blob/master/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) (default layout) and [here](https://github.com/symfony/twig-bridge/blob/master/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig) (Bootstrap).

In your case you'd need to modify the `form_errors` block:

```
{%- block form_errors -%}
    {%- if errors|length > 0 -%}
    <ul>
        {%- for error in errors -%}
             <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
        {%- endfor -%}
    </ul>
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_errors -%}
```

To choose for one such layout, adjust the config as desired:

```
twig:
    form_themes:

        # Default:
        - form_div_layout.html.twig

        # Bootstrap
        - bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig

        # Your own:
        - MyBundle::form.html.twig
```

(taken from [Twig reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html))

Read more about customizing the form themes on the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html).

Comment: Thank you for replaying ,i really appreciate , so first i'm using matriel design bootstrap for the theme .
Second ,can you specefie the file where i gonna modify the form_errors block  .

Comment: You can create your own Twig file in the `app/Resources/views` directory and then place the `form_errors`. block inside it.